# About planar graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

Can any non-planar graph with n minimum crossing points  be 'drawn' on a sphere  so the vertice and edge sets are the same and it has a connected subset A with minimum r crossing points and a disjoint connected subset B with minimum s crossing points where r+s=n? And other subsets can be found for any value r such that 1 < r < n ?

Comment: I downvoted the question because it is definitely not research level; further I miss some clarification, what kind of graphs and transformation you have in mind. A planar graph and the embedding of a graph in the euclidean plane are different things; so do you actually have geometric embeddings in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Suppose it could, then you could just apply the steriographic projection from an interior point of some face on the sphere and obtain a graph on the plane with no crossing edges that is isomorphic to yours. Hence your graph must have been planar.

Comment: Could a non-planar graph be 'translated' from a plane to a torus or some other surface in 3-D space and have no crossing points?

Comment: This is obvious, isn't it? Make you graph thick (ribbon graph) and patch the holes. Wrong question for this site.

Comment: It is not completely obvious to me though that you will actualy end up with a surface after using your patching procedure.

Answer (score 1):

No, it has the wrong graph genus.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphGenus.html